# Java program that generates a random integer, and counts the number of occurrence

Tags: java, arrays, random, count

I am trying to make a program that helps how many times user could flip the coin which user can flip up to 1000 times. In more detail, I am trying to make the program that generate a random integer between 1 and 10 (even = head, odd = tail), and store all the numbers in an array (size set by the number of coin flips).

And this is what I did so far:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinFlippingTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try (Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("How many times do you want to flip the coin?: ");
            int amount = inputReader.nextInt();
            
            Map<Integer, Integer> flips = new HashMap<>();
            
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                
                flips.put(i, 0);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                
                int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                flips.put(randomNumber, flips.get(randomNumber) + 1);
            }
            
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : flips.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

I want to create a program where numbers come out randomly and the numbers overlap to a minimum, but this is what comes out:

```
How many times do you want to flip the coin?: 
10
1: 2
2: 0
3: 1
4: 1
5: 4
6: 2
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
10: 0
```

What I am trying to be expecting is this:

With newly created array, I need to supply the following information:

1. how many times do each of the 10 random numbers occur,
2. which number occurred most often,
3. which side of the coin came up more often

The task description that I need to do shows that I need to do this:

1. Create and use a method that generates a random integer between (and including) integers a and b: random(a,b)
2. Create and use a method that counts the number of occurrence of a certain value n from a given array arr: count(n,arr)

I tried to fix it many times by looking at the examples, but it got stuck here. Please give me any suggestions or answers would be helpful. Even a little advice, I will be really appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: What exactly does not work, and in what form does it not work? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], as we as expected and observed output.

Comment: This feels a bit like homework.  I think you need to figure out one thing that is not working, and ask for help with that.  Your current code basically has nothing working and you want help writing the whole thing, that's not like to get a response.

Comment: You wrote too much code with too many errors.  Break your task into steps.  First, just generate random numbers and make sure they fall in the 1 to 10 range.  Run lots of tests until you are confident that the random number code works.  Next, just save the random numbers in an array.  Print the array to make sure you're saving the values correctly.  Next, use the random numbers array to create a value array.  In other words, if your random numbers array is `4, 2, 6. 1, 3`, then your value array would be `1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0`.  Run dozens of tests to verify the value array.

Answer (score 0):

Your result per se does not show any problem.

```
How many times do you want to flip the coin?: 
10
1: 2
2: 0
3: 1
4: 1
5: 4
6: 2
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
10: 0
```

You need to approach random numbers from a different perspective.
Assume you have an infinite sequence of random numbers. Could this sequence contain a strip of say, 1000 consecutives zeros? The answer is 'unlikely, but yes it can contain such a strip'.

But when you create random numbers in a test program, and there are one thousand consecutive numbers - all of them being zero - everyone would question the random number generator...

So you need a closer look at running your code with different random seeds. If the pattern remains the same, analyze your code. Maybe add more System.out.println, or learn how to use a debugger.